# Deserialize a Json file in Python after C# (for convert to image from byte[])

Tags: python, json, base64

I have a drawing that I converted to an array of bytes, then serialized it to a JSON file using C # code.
When deserializing this JSON file in Python, I don't get the byte array I need.
As a result, I want to get a drawing converted from bytes.
Tell me, what needs to be done in order to finally get a picture?

Json file:

```
{"Image":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQ0AAAL9CAIAAAC+CqTbAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAAOwwAADsMBx2+oZAAAE3lJREFUeF7t3e+r52ldx/H9E/oPu .... "}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFNQP.jpg)
Python:

```
with open(filename, "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
```

Comment: Well Python has no way of knowing that that string is a base64 encoded byte array so you get it as what it is a string. Just base64 decode the string. The better question is: Why not simply store the image as an image instead of using json? That's completely unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, I see that it is represented as a string.
And how can I convert this string into an array of bytes, tell me please.

Comment: besides the image itself, I have to pass the properties of the object from C #, so I want to keep everything in one JSON file.

Comment: As I said: It's a Base64 encoded string, so just decode it and you've got your image.

Comment: You can accept your own answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img_encode = base64.b64decode(data['Image'])
```